# How can I achieve concurrency without using a while loop or recursion?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, concurrency

I have a table with a composite ID of two keys: `ItemType` which can be one of the following `('BIG', 'MED', 'SML')` and `ItemNumber` which can be any number in range of `0-9999`. The goal of the assignment is to manage concurrency so the requests of `INSERT` for the table are correct and non-repeated, like this: `BIG0001, BIG0002, BIG0003`. Also, the table has a RowNumber column of type Int, which serves the purpose of grouping (the teacher laid that requeriment).

I have read several SQL Server articles on this subject and somehow I managed to get a working example, but I feel that this can be done much better. I'm actually using a try/catch block and recursion. Why? Because I'm getting deadlocks, once the deadlock is thrown it falls to the catch and then I execute the stored procedure again. But a problem arises from this approach: The stack size. Stored procedure calls have a determined stack size and passing the 150 concurrent executions I get an error because of that.

This is my code:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Item (
  RowNumber INT NOT NULL,
  ItemNumber INT NOT NULL,
  ItemType CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT ItemTypeEnum CHECK(ItemType IN ('BIG', 'MED', 'SML')),
  CONSTRAINT MaxItemNumber CHECK(ItemNumber BETWEEN 0 AND 9999),
  PRIMARY KEY (ItemNumber, ItemType)
);
GO
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE RegisterItem @ItemType CHAR(3)
AS
  BEGIN
      BEGIN TRY
          SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
          BEGIN TRANSACTION [RegisterItem]
            DECLARE @LastRowNumber INT;
            DECLARE @LastItemNumber INT;
            SELECT @LastRowNumber = COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 RowNumber FROM Item WITH (HOLDLOCK, ROWLOCK) WHERE ItemType = @ItemType ORDER BY RowNumber DESC), 0) + 1;
            SELECT @LastItemNumber = COALESCE((SELECT TOP 1 ItemNumber FROM Item WITH (HOLDLOCK, ROWLOCK) WHERE ItemType = @ItemType ORDER BY RowNumber DESC), 0) + 1;
            INSERT INTO Camion(ItemType, RowNumber, ItemNumber) VALUES(@ItemType, @LastRowNumber, @LastItemNumber);
          COMMIT TRANSACTION [RegisterItem]
      END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [RegisterItem];
          EXEC RegisterItem @ItemType
      END CATCH
  END
GO
```

I made a small script in `NodeJS` that sends 100 concurrent requests to the server, and I get the errors of maximum stored procedure stack size exceeded and sometimes a deadlock. How can I achieve, let's say, sending the maximum amount of requests (which will be 9999 for each item) without errors, duplicated information, or information loss?

Comment: it seems like your `rownumber` and `itemnumber` has always same value, since they both are updated by `+1` at same time.

Comment: Yes, they do. @DarkRob. Since both elements start from 0 and go up to 9999, I don't see why they shouldn't be always the same. Or is there something I'm not seeing?

Comment: Put your retry mechanism outside this SP to avoid the nesting limit.

Comment: Is it correct if I made another stored procedure that calls the RegisterItem one and check for failures and then call itself again?

Comment: Yes, make another SP which calls this one from a loop until either it succeeds or the max attempts is passed. That way you aren't nesting attempts. Or do it in code.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the same if I just used a loop from the main stored procedure? That way I'm not using another procedure, I'll just be catching the error thrown.

Comment: Fair point, yes you can just do that.

Comment: And then use the execution plan and deadlock graph to find out what the issue is. To be honest these kind of locking scenarios are often hard to get fast due to the necessary locks to ensure you don't allocate duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. Instead of saving your value in a variable and then use it for save you may directly call use `INSERT...SELECT` to insert your record in your table.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE RegisterItem @ItemType CHAR(3)
AS
  BEGIN
      BEGIN TRY
          SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
          BEGIN TRANSACTION [RegisterItem]
            INSERT INTO Camion(ItemType, RowNumber, ItemNumber)    ---- here are you sure your table name is correct 
            SELECT @ItemType, ISNULL(MAX(RowNumber)+1,1), ISNULL(MAX(ItemNumber)+1,1) FROM Item WHERE ItemType = @ItemType GROUP BY ItemType

          COMMIT TRANSACTION [RegisterItem]
      END TRY
      BEGIN CATCH
          ROLLBACK TRANSACTION [RegisterItem];
          EXEC RegisterItem @ItemType    ---- why you are calling this again..?
      END CATCH
  END
```

Comment: Sorry, the table is written in spanish so I did translate it and the stored procedure to english haha. I'll try your example, thanks!. And Im calling the stored procedure again from itself because when concurrent requests arrive I get deadlocks and execution stops. So, when I get an error due to that I call the stored procedure again as a retry strategy.